# Vue - Content of contenteditable is doubling without variable change

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have 4 contenteditables which I am copying to a variable.

If I write "1234" in Path2, then change to Title1 and then defocus Title1, then Path2 will change to "12341234", but the variable `this.PC.Path2` will still be "1234".

This error occurs on only content editable - Path2.
I have changed the name so only the Function `updateHtml` can interact with it(on my site) - no effect.

```
<div class="PathContainer" v-on:click="focusPath2">
      <div class="namespace edit path" contenteditable="true" @blur="updateHtml" name="Path">{{PC.Path}}</div>
      <div class="path editPath2" contenteditable="true" @blur="updateHtml" name="Path2" ref="Path2" >{{PC.Path2}}</div>
</div>
Title1: <span class="edit" contenteditable="true" @blur="updateHtml" name="Title2">{{ PC.Title2 }}</span><br>
Title2: <span class="edit" contenteditable="true" @blur="updateHtml" name="Title1">{{ PC.Title1 }}</span>

updateHtml: function(e) {
      var foo = e.target.getAttribute("name")
      console.log("PATH2---", this.PC.Path2);
      this.PC[foo] = e.target.innerText;
      console.log("PATH2---", this.PC.Path2);
      console.log("UPDATING this.PC." + foo, "  to-->", this.PC[foo]);
},
```

The Complete Code with Backend is on: https://github.com/i5heu/wikinota/tree/V2

Only the Code of this Module: https://github.com/i5heu/wikinota-web/blob/04629560ec0d6383b4ad8f92cb2647a616c559ce/js/pedit.js

Here is the Chrome Performance Profile. (with Pictures of the weird stuff)
[weird-bug.zip](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/files/1885385/wierd-bug.zip)

I'm using Vue.js v2.5.16.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround for this problem.

I think the problem is in the DOM engine of Vue.
So you have to trigger the DOM engine again to overwrite the content of the content-editable.

This is achieved by 1 Line.

```
updateHtml: function(e) {
  var foo = e.target.getAttribute("name");

  console.log("PATH2---", this.PC.Path2);

  this.PC[foo] = e.target.innerText;
  e.target.innerText = this.PC[foo]; //<<<< This is the workaround

  console.log("PATH2---", this.PC.Path2);
  console.log("UPDATING this.PC." + foo, "  to-->", this.PC[foo]);
}
```